# I don't know why this statement wont run correctly

Tags: python, if-statement

I have to make this program for my teacher to grade her students, and I don't know why my if-else statement won't run correctly.

```
    i = 0
    y = input("\nWas your student exempted for English Post Midterm Exam? (Yes/No)")
    if y.lower == "yes":
        i += 1
        eng_p = "Exem"
        eng_ia = int(input("\nEnter English internal assesment marks (out of 10)-> "))
        if(eng_ia < 0 or eng_ia > 10): 
            print("\nInvalid Input")
            eng_ia = int(input("Enter English internal assesment marks (out of 10)-> "))
            a = input("\nWas your student exempted for English Annual exam? (Yes/No)")
            if a.lower == "yes":
                i += 1
                eng_an = "Exem"
                eng_t = (4 + eng_ia + 32)/100
            else:
                eng_an = int(input("Enter English annual exam marks (out of 80)-> "))
                if(eng_an < 0 or eng_an > 80): 
                    print("\nInvalid Input")
                    eng_an = int(input("Enter English annual exam marks (out of 80)-> "))
                    eng_t = (4 + eng_ia + eng_an)/100
    else:
        eng_p = int(input("Enter English post mid term marks (out of 10)-> "))
```

My code runs the first line of the if statement but then runs the else block.

Output:

```
Was your student exempted from English Post Midterm Exam? (Yes/No)yes
Enter English post mid-term marks (out of 10)-\> ???
```

Comment: Hi Viper, can you please format your code so we can read it? Just bookend the code in triple ticks: ```

Comment: Hi josh, I have fixed the formatting, let me know if you have any solutions

Comment: `y.lower` should be `y.lower()`.  Same with `a.lower`.  (Those are regular methods, not properties, so you have to explicitly call them with `()` if you want to get a string out of them.)

Comment: Omg, I cant believe it was such a small issue, and I never caught it. Thank you so much!